# How to fill column A based on another column?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I have 4 columns (Address1, Address2, and latlon).

Columns Address1 and Address2 are basically the same; except that Address1 contains the same addresses with Address2 multiplied N times.

The figure below shows a sample of the Address1 column:

Address1 Column Sample in Excel:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/paS8B.png]

The 2nd figure is a sample of the dataframe with dropped repetitive addresses in column Address2:

Address 2 column with geocoded lat and lon:

[image]

I want to automatically place the lat and lon that matches with the address2 column to the address1 columns; however, they are not of the same length since address1 contains address2 multiple times

I recently took the column Address2 and dropped the repetitive addresses.

I then geocoded them (Address2) to get another column with latlon values.

Now, I want to place these latlon values into the original (Address1) column which contains more than 8000 rows.

Is there any function I could use directly with python to do this?

I am thinking of creating a new column for address1 such that each specific address is a number in the new column, then do the same for the address2 column and then match them (latlon) based on this? but, how do I code this in python once I create the new columns.

I am new to python and am still learning. Hoping someone could give some ideas or point me to the right way on how to go on with this.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put sample input/desired output and what have you tried so far?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Sorry for the confusing question, I've edited it now. I have only tried manually doing this, and thought that there could be a way to automate it.

Comment: Do you want to do it in pure python? I use Linux and don't have Excel, but in pure python this is easy.

Comment: Hi! @AndrejKesely Yeah, I would rather do it in pure python; however, I´m not sure where to start.